# How to change the value of a boolean in a model after a certain period of time in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a rental application in Django which has a boolean field rental_status.

```
rental_status = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

- rental_status describes if the product is already rented or is available to rent.
- the default value is true i.e is available for rent.
- Consider a situation where a person rents out the product for x
  amount of time and we change the rental_status to false.

So, My question is how can we change rental_status to true after x time so that it can be rented again.

(I understand if my way of implementation is not good or ideal but it is just for a project. Please suggest if there are any other better implementations)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the date until which it is rented somewhere too, eg.

```
rented_until = models.DateField("Rented until date", null=True)
```

If there are no other conditions for the `rental_status`, then you dont need that field anymore and you can use only this one.

To find out unrented properties, use `filter()` with a value of date you are interested in (eventually take into consideration potential `null` value too):

```
# find properties which are available from today further on 
MyModel.objects.filter(rented_until__lt=date.today())
```